# C++ получить случайное число

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Есть ли какие-то другие способы получить случайное число в определённом диапазоне? `rand()` для имеющейся задачи вообще не подходит. Например, я написал консольную игру, где у героя есть шанс критического удара. У меня на компьютере почти каждый 3-й удар - критический (с шансами 26%), а на компьютере у друга с такими же шансами не факт, что вообще будет критический удар.

`srand(time(0));` прописан.

Делаю так:

```
if (rand()%100 > critical_chance) {...}
```

Comment: Если у Вас шанс 26, и прописано `if (rand()%100 > critical_chance) {...}`, то условие будет выполняться в 73/100. Поменяйте знак > на <=.

Comment: Там ошибка в знаке в вопросе. Перепутал) "<" стоит

Comment: Ну, 26 из 100 - это и есть почти каждый третий. Точнее, каждый четвёртый. Не понял, в чём вообще проблема. И у кого "у него"?

Comment: У друга. Извиняюсь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В C++ имеются разные генераторы случайных чисел, с разными распределениями. Но в данном случае это неважно, поскольку для такой простой цели `rand()` вполне адекватен, хотя, конечно, его диапазон не так уж велик. И еще - `srand(time(0));` - это просто добавление случайности, не более того, но не воздействие на свойства генератора.

Простейший тест

```
int chances(int value)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        if (rand()%100 < value) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    srand(time(0));
    for(int value = 0; value < 100; value += 10)
    {
        int count = chances(value);
        printf("%3d :  %3d.%01d\n",value, count/10,count%10);
    }
}
```

Дает на Visual C++ 2015 результат (понятно, что с колебаниями от запуска к запуску)

```
  0 :    0.0
 10 :   11.3
 20 :   22.1
 30 :   29.7
 40 :   40.7
 50 :   51.5
 60 :   59.2
 70 :   70.6
 80 :   79.0
 90 :   89.9
```

[Здесь](http://ideone.com/aMA2Wa) можно посмотреть результат для GCC.

Можете - если хотите - воспользоваться вариантом

```
std::default_random_engine u{};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{};

u.seed(std::random_device()()); // Аналог srand

d(u,uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type{0,100}); // - аналог rand()%100
```

Еще корректнее в данном случае использовать

```
bernoulli_distribution b;

// Замена вашего if (rand()%100 < critical_chance)
if (b(u,std::bernoulli_distribution::param_type{critical_chance/100.0})) { ... };
```

Comment: `rand` не может быть адекватен, даже для такой простой задачи, т.к. неизвестно какое он даёт распределение и, в силу своей ограниченности, он biased.

Comment: @ixSci Равномерность генератора проверяется в любом случае. Он может не проходить тесты на какую-нибудь автокорреляцию, но для простейшего варианта выбора шансов он точно отработает. Так, чтобы не было ни одного раза при пороге 26% - грубо говоря, не будет такого (не)счастья. Да, для трех попыток - поверю, но это может дать любой генератор, даже квантовый :) Покажите пример хоть одного *современного* компилятора, где ГСЧ не пройдет хи-квадрат на равномерность...

Comment: В каком любом? Кто Вам сказал, что rand() выдаёт равномерное распределение? Где это написано?

Comment: Я не понимаю, в чём сложность писать в ответах на нормальном C++? В обоих стандартах(C и C++) `rand()` разными словами признаётся устаревшим, а люди упорно продолжают его писать в своих ответах. Буду ставить минусы за `rand()` в ответах.

Comment: @ixSci Как говорится, вам надо шашечки или надо ехать? Пусть я неправ, но лично у меня необходимость писать 5 строк длиннющего кода с непроизносимыми именами вместо простого rand() - который давно можно было построить на основе более современных генераторов - вызывает отторжение не меньшее, чем библиотека <chrono> с ее бешеным многословием... Кстати, не только у меня - у некоторых членов комитета тоже :)

Comment: Это образовательный ресурс, и, с моей точки зрения, здесь должны собираться современные идеи и реализации, а не минимальной кровью отделываться от вопрошающих.

Comment: Поэтому сейчас пытаются упростить базовое использование `random`. Возможно, к 20-у году появится простая в использовании функция.

Comment: @ixSci `RDRAND`

Comment: А как в обратную сторону? Т.е. есть шанс промаха, и нужно записать это: if (rand()%100 > enemy->getMissChance()) {...}  с использованием Bernoulli

Comment: @J.Doe, я про C++ говорил.

Answer (score 1):

Заголовочный файл `<random>` для C++11 включает генерацию ПСЧ для разных кривых распределения: равномерное, Бернули, нормальное. Если без поддержки C++11, то этот модуль входит в библиотеку boost.

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что вероятности нужно перемножать, учитывая неудачи на предыдущих ходах

```
double getProb(double AProb, int AIdx) {
  return 1 - (1 - AProb) * (AIdx + 1);
}

for (int i = 0; life > 0; i++) {
  if rand() < getProb(critical_chance, i) {
    ..........
  }
}
```

Comment: Почему надо так?

Comment: События независимы, не нужно ничего перемножать.